# Regex to match repeated pattern after a string

Tags: regex

I need a regex that extract pattern after specific word (her like **Limits::**)

i have teststring ,So let's say the text is always between delimiter !Limits::****! :

> *ksjfl kfj  sdfasdfaf dfasf asd sdf a dfasd fdaf ad f  afdfaf dfad bla bla ksfajs ldsfskj !Limits::**WLo1**/**WHi1**/**WHi1**/**WHi1**,**WLo2**/**WHi2**/**WHi**/**WHi2**,.hier repeated pattern..,**WLon**/**WHin**/**CLon**/**CHin**!
>   fasdfakl skdfkas sflas fasf sdf afasf

i just want only words :

1. WLo1
2. WHi1
3. WHi1
4. WHi1
5. WLo2
6. WHi2
7. WHi
8. WHi2
9. .
10. .
11. .
12. WLon
13. WHin
14. CLon
15. CHin

i have tested like (?:!\w+::(?:(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)))|(?:,(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+))+.*!, with fail

Comment: only regular expression, lik java script

Comment: Start by capturing what's between delimiters `!Limits::([\S\s]+?)!`. From that capture, figure out the words you need to get.

Comment: I've already tried with this pattern, but unfortunately did not work

Comment: It is not possible to do with pure regex in JavaScript. Please reconsider your requirements. Else, I suggest closing the question. BTW, maybe you just look to get all 4 character words starting with uppercase letter? [`\b[A-Z]\w{3}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/wV8gC3/1)?

Comment: I want to save regex in database for Reise with PHP and JavaScript. Thinks

Comment: this patter match everything in pattern as ABC1  bevor position string Limits::

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions:

`/(W.*|C.*)(?=\/|!|,)/g` : match words beginning with `W` or `C` followed by `/` , `!`, or `,`

`/\/|,.*(?=,)|,/` : remove `/` or `,` or any characters followed by `,` or `,` from string returned from first `RegExp`

```js
var str = "*ksjfl kfj sdfasdfaf dfasf asd sdf a dfasd fdaf ad f afdfaf dfad bla bla ksfajs ldsfskj !Limits::WLo1/WHi1/WHi1/WHi1,WLo2/WHi2/WHi/WHi2,.hier repeated pattern..,WLon/WHin/CLon/CHin! fasdfakl skdfkas sflas fasf sdf afasf";

var res = str.match(/(W.*|C.*)(?=\/|!|,)/g)[0].split(/\/|,.*(?=,)|,/);

document.body.textContent = res.join(" ")
```

Comment: `.split()` accepts a regular expression as parameter as demonstrated at stacksnippets

Comment: just only regular expression

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the ending delimiter is, so if it matters, update your question and I'll amend this expression:

```
/(?<=Limits::)(?:(.+?)\/)+/i
```

Searches for `Limits::`, then repeating strings ending with `/`, your words will be in group 1.